# Consulta de duas ou mais tabelas pdo mssql

Tags: php, sql-server, pdo, php-7

Consulta de duas ou mais tabelas pdo mssql, a conexão está normal.

Estou com uma certa dificuldade.

Tenho 2 tabelas.

perfil

id | nome | datanascimento | Endereço

conexoes

id | idperfil | data

Estou tentando chamar as duas tabelas para o usuário logado tenha acesso, mais quando tento nada aparece. Quando uso somente chamando uma tabela aparece mais quando chamo as duas só aparece a que vem em primeiro na ordem.

Como está meu script:

```
$sql2 = "select nome, datanascimento, Endereço from perfil where id = '$id'";
$stm2 = $conn->prepare($sql2);  
$stm2->execute();  
$row = $stm2->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$sql3 = "select id, data from conexoes where idperfil = '$id'";
$stm3 = $conn->prepare($sql3);  
$stm3->execute();  
$roww = $stm3->fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
```

Na hora de chamar, uso o

```
<?php echo $roww['DisConnectTM'];?>
```

Comment: pq não faz um unico select com join entre as duas tabelas?

Comment: Não entendi muito bem a dúvida mas é possível fazer um JOIN entre as 2 tabelas e assim fazer apenas uma consulta? Pois existe o ID e IDPERFIL, se forem o mesmo valor você pode fazer esse JOIN e filtrar pelo ID da pessoa depois.